# Serial comunication between Arduino and STM32 F401RE with Arduino IDE

Tags: serial

How can I pass through the serial port a number from an Arduino to the STM32 F401RE? Using the Arduino IDE? For now I have done this:

(I should do all this using just the Arduino IDE)

Code Arduino (TX):

```
int valueTX = 5;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print(valueTX);
  delay(500);
}
```

Code STM32 F401RE (RX):

```
int valueRX;

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    valueRX = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(valueRX);
  }
}
```

But the STM32 F401RE does not print 5, but -1; I do not understand why.

Comment: Can you try to copy-paste the code properly? As it is now, the STM32 code would not even compile, due Serial.available maybe missing a bracket. Edit the post to contain the exact code you are using. The Serial.read() will return -1 if there is no bytes available, so you may be doing something wrong.

Comment: I apologize very much, I fixed the code.

Comment: "(I should do all this using just the Arduino IDE)" do you know that Arduino IDE is for Arduino? STM32 is not officially supported.